# Javascript Rollovers

Tags: javascript, rollovers

I am fairly new to JavaScript and I am trying to make it so that when you `mouseover` a link, an image to the right of the page changes, then changes back on `mouseout`.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function SwapOut(titleid){
if (titleid == video)
    document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/videotitle.png"
else if (titleid == gamedesign)
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/gametitle.png"       
else if (titleid == webdesign)
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/webtitle.png"    
return true;
}

function SwapBack('titleid'){
if (titleid == home)
    document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/hometitle.png"
else if (titleid == gamedesign)
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/gametitle.png"   
else if (titleid == video)
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/videotitle.png"  
else if (titleid == webdesign)
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/webtitle.png" 
return true;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<a id="eileenSmall1" href="video.html" onmouseover="SwapOut('video')" onmouseout="SwapBack('home')"></a>

<div id="title">
    <img src="images/hometitle.png" name="titleimg"/>
</div>
```

I would normally approach this with CSS but was having issues getting it to work as I am changing the properties of a different element. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your trying to refer to an element with the `id` "titleimg", yet you haven't given the element an `id` at all.

2) Your `if` condition doesn't compare `titleid` with a string it compares it to what it thinks is a variable.. For example it should be `'video'` not `video`.

3) In your second function your parameter should be a variable not a string.. For example it should be `SwapBack(titleid)` not `SwapBack('titleid')`.

You should try this...

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function SwapOut(titleid){
if (titleid == 'video')
    document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/videotitle.png"
else if (titleid == 'gamedesign')
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/gametitle.png"       
else if (titleid == 'webdesign')
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/webtitle.png"    
return true;
}

function SwapBack(titleid){
if (titleid == 'home')
    document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/hometitle.png"
else if (titleid == 'gamedesign')
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/gametitle.png"   
else if (titleid == 'video')
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/videotitle.png"  
else if (titleid == 'webdesign')
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/webtitle.png" 
return true;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a id="eileenSmall1" href="video.html" onmouseover="SwapOut('video')" onmouseout="SwapBack('home')"></a>

<div id="title">
    <img src="images/hometitle.png" name="titleimg" id="titleimg" />
</div>
```

Comment: The mouseover is working now, thanks! However, the mouseout still isn't working, the image does not return to the original.

Comment: Nevermind, file naming error on my part. Everything is working great now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you're referencing titleimg by id but haven't assigned it an id, just a name

```
 <img src="images/hometitle.png" name="titleimg" id="titleimg"/>
```

also, the parameter you pass into your function is a string variable. Your functions should look like

```
function SwapOut(titleid){
if (titleid == 'video')
    document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/videotitle.png"
else if (titleid == 'gamedesign')
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/gametitle.png"       
else if (titleid == 'webdesign')
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/webtitle.png"    
return true;
}

function SwapBack(titleid){
if (titleid == 'home')
    document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/hometitle.png"
else if (titleid == 'gamedesign')
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/gametitle.png"   
else if (titleid == 'video')
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/videotitle.png"  
else if (titleid == 'webdesign')
   document.getElementById("titleimg").src="images/webtitle.png" 
return true;
}
```

paying attention to the quotes, you're comparing strings, for example

titleid == 'home' vs titleid == home

also lose the quotations in function SwapBack('titleid')

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `if (titleid == video)` isn't valid - you're trying to reference video as a variable that doesn't exist. It should be `if (titleid == 'video')` to signify that it's a string of text.

Secondly, you don't need that if logic in there. Where you're doing `onmouseover="SwapOut('video')"` you could instead pass it the image.

e.g.,

```
function swapOut(img)
{
    document.getElementById('titleimg').src = img;
}
```

HTML

```
<a id="eileenSmall1" href="video.html" onmouseover="SwapOut('images/videotitle.png')"></a>
```

Swapback doesn't need any conditional logic (assuming you always want to switch the image back to home).